# How to connect admin panel to socket

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I have created a chat application using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) server and android client.
I have a administrator panel for managing users that connected to node using [socket.io](http://socket.io/). I can call node.js server functions from admin panel using get or post methods, but I want to do that using socket connection.